# Screen goes blank of React Typescript application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4

Hey I am creating a react type script app and suddenly my screen goes blank then after a hard refresh it goes back normal i am confused because i am unable to detect the cause and console show no errors in it. But i had some doubts in my routing and my index.html file might be cause.

Here is my App.tsx file

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Careers from './components/Careers';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Newsroom from './components/Newsroom';
import Awareness from './components/Awareness';
import Products from './components/Products';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './Store';
import Legal from './components/Legal';
import SponsoredProgram from './components/SponsoredProgram';

const App: FC<any> = (props) => {

  // props.i18n.changeLanguage("en");

  return (
    <Provider store={store} >
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route exact path='/careers' component={Careers} />
        <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact} />
        <Route exact path='/newsroom' component={Newsroom} />
        <Route exact path='/awareness' component={Awareness} />
        <Route exact path='/products/:id' component={Products} />
        <Route exact path='/sponsored-program' component={SponsoredProgram} />
        <Route exact path='/help-center' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/safety-center' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/community-guidelines' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/privacy-policy' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/terms&conditions' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/copyrights' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/ccpa' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/gdpr' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/legal' component={Legal} />
      </Switch>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default withTranslation()(withRouter(App) as React.ComponentType<any>);
```

And here is my index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { I18nextProvider } from "react-i18next";
import './index.css';
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import i18n from './i18n';

ReactDOM.render(
  <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </I18nextProvider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.register();
```

Comment: Is there any error on the console? If you haven't set an error boundary the page will just turn white on a fatal error.

Comment: @Robin No error show on the console but i had a second doubt about bootstrap or jquery import issue might be

Comment: Because react screen blanks on javascript error

Answer (score 0):

I think i my index.html file is culprit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/responsive.css">
    
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="js/custom.tsx"></script> -->
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/slider.js" ></script> -->
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Company Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

When ever i uncomment out the scripting tags e.g  it goes blank. but still doesn't know the cause. I hope someone have some understanding of it